# AWS EC2 Instance lost its internet after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am really not good with servers. What happened is that I rebooted my EC2 Instance with Ubuntu as the Operating System. I rebooted it via the EC2 Instance console.

Now when it turned back on, it seems it can't connect to the Internet. I noticed this one because I have a web server in my instance then it says "Please check your Internet connection and try again", then I also try to download some packages, it also says "failed to fetch..."

Is there a way to turn the Internet back on?

I need help with this because my live server isn't working!

Comment: Do you have a NIC attached? Try restarting the network service?

Comment: Hi @Peter - where can i find that NIC? and how do i restart the network service? I tried doing this `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` and this `sudo systemctl restart system-networkd` - it says `..service not found.`

Comment: By the way @Peter - i saw that there's a Network Interface attached to this instance - https://www.screencast.com/t/cycxjyPf